# std::stringstream not reading whitespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, whitespace

```
    template< typename T >
    T Read( const char* Section, const char* Key )
    {
        SecureZeroMemory( m_Result, sizeof( m_Result ) );
        GetPrivateProfileString( Section, Key, 0, m_Result, sizeof( m_Result ), m_File.FullPath );
        std::istringstream Cast( m_Result );
        T Result{ };
        Cast >> std::noskipws >> Result;
        return Result;
    }
```

m_Result is a member variable of my class. ( char[256] ).

Objective: Try to return all types that i insert on template arg.

Issue: When i send std::string with: "Example Text Return" it returns me "Example" instead of "Example Text Return".

Where is the error? I tried a lot of skipws or noskipws or ws...

Sorry for the english, i'm a brazilian guy.

Comment: @Cainan : Good one for a first question here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::noskipws` only reads any initial whitespace. The `>>` operator overload for a `std::string` always stops reading the string at the first encountered whitespace character. `std::noskipws` makes it read the initial whitespace, but the conversion still stops at the first whitespace character following the first non-whitespace character.

What you need to do is to specialize this template function for a `std::string`, and just return the `m_Result` without any conversion.

Comment: Ok, but i wanna to use that function like this: int Key = Read<int>( "Section", "Key" ); Thats why i used a template function. But if dont have another solution, i'll overload for const char*.

Comment: There's nothing in my answer that is contrary to what you intend to do. Your template function remains unchanged, all that's needed is an explicit specialization for a std::string. And not for a const char *, by the way.

Comment: Thank you, i found a solution. I cant vote ur answer :( sorry hehe.